# Are WAN same as autonomous systems(AS)?

Tags: network, wan

I am currently studying network+. I came across this question that are autonomous systems(AS) same as the WAN ?
or they are two things completely apart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completely different things.

WAN - wide area network - is a collective term for wide range networking technology, with perhaps 1-100 km reach; often it is also used to refer to the Internet in general.

An Autonomous System is an administrative domain or entity for organizing the exchange of routing prefixes via BGP on the Internet.